# Why does new Object("foo") return "[object Object]"

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, type-conversion

```
Array.prototype.sort.call("foo"); // "[object Object]"
Array.prototype.sort.call(true); // true
Array.prototype.sort.call(1); // 1
Array.prototype.sort.call([1]); // [1]
Array.prototype.sort.call({}); // {}
Array.prototype.sort.call(function() {}); // function() {}
```

Why does the calling an array method on a string act differently? I presume it's because `String` also has `.length` and `[]` element accessors.

Can anyone explain what exactly happens when you call native methods on the wrong type?

**[Edit]**

Woops I solved it.

```
new Object("foo"); // "[object Object]"
```

It acts the same for the rest.

Let's speak to the ES5 spec:

> 15.2.1.1 Object ( [ value ] ) When the Object function is called with no
>   arguments or with one argument  value,
>   the following steps are  taken:
>
> 1. If value is null, undefined or not supplied, create and return a new
>      Object object exactly as if the
>      standard  built-in Object constructor
>      had been called with the same
>      arguments (15.2.2.1).
> 2. Return ToObject(value)

And `ToObject` is :

> 9.9 ToObject The abstract operation ToObject converts its argument to a
>   value of type Object according to
>   Table 14:
>
> Table 14 — ToObject Argument
>   Type Result
>
> Undefined Throw a
>   TypeError exception.
>
> Null Throw a
>   TypeError exception.
>
> Boolean Create a
>   new Boolean object whose
>   [[PrimitiveValue]] internal property
>   is  set to the value of the  argument.
>   See 15.6 for a description of Boolean 
>   objects.
>
> Number Create a new Number
>   object whose [[PrimitiveValue]] 
>   internal  property is  set to the
>   value of the  argument. See 15.7 for a
>   description of Number  objects.
>
> String
>   Create a new String object whose
>   [[PrimitiveValue]] internal property
>   is set  to the value of the argument.
>   See 15.5 for a description of String
>   objects. Object The result is the
>   input argument (no conversion).

**[Bounty]**

Now why is `[[PrimitiveValue]]` of `String` equal to `"[object Object]"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'problem' here is that the constructors for that type are called (`Number, String, Array, Boolean...`), which act a little different than their "primitive" counterparts - they return an object that contains a primitive value.

This [[PrimitiveValue]], or [[value]] in previous specifications, is an internal property which you can access via `.valueOf()`.

```
'foo' // is a string
String('foo') // is a string
new String('foo') // is a String object with [[value]] set to 'foo'

1 // is a number
Number(1) // is a number
new Number(1) // is a Number object with [[value]] set to 1

Object('foo') == (new String('foo'))
Object(1) == (new Number(1))
```

For some reason the webkit inspector doesn't seem aware of these object's primitive value. So, `Object('foo')` will print '[object Object]', but if you call `Object('foo').toString()` or any method that implicitly calls toString or valueOf, like `alert(Object('foo'))`, you get the expected value "foo".

That's also the cause of this:

```
var x = new Boolean(false);
// any object evaluates to true...
!!x // == true
Boolean(x) // == true
```

Javascript has it's fair share of weirdness. Also consider that there are plenty of quirks in javascript engines, with varying levels of compliance with the specs.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm just wondering what the webkit inspector is doing not showing the primitive vallue.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your question

> Now why is [[PrimitiveValue]] of String equal to "[object Object]" ?

You must turn to the ECMAscript [standard doc](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) section 15.4.4.11

"*Let obj be the result of calling ToObject passing the this value as the argument.*"

When you `Array.prototype.call("abc")` 'this' is the string "abc". Passing that string into ToObject is the same as calling `new Object("abc")`, and this is done implicitly.

Also, it is worthwhile noting that `Array.prototype.sort.call("foo")` generates a TypeError in FF4.

**TypeError: Array.prototype.sort.call("foo") is read-only**

This is likey due the requirement (also in the spec) that the sort algorithm is not defined if "*Any array index property of obj whose name is a nonnegative integer less than len is a data property
whose [[Configurable]] attribute is false.*"

Strings can not be altered with [] accessors. Try it for yourself

```
var test = "abc";
test[1] = 'x';
console.log(test) //'abc'
```

FF4 is most likely being a bit more strict in following the spec

Comment: Why is `new Object("abc") === "[object Object]"`. That's where I'm stuck. I've run through the spec as you mentioned.

Comment: If you test `typeof new Object('abc')` you will see that it is "object" not "string", so this is normal. The browser is chosing to log it as a string most likely because it sees the .toString() method on the object. The browser is chosing to log it as `(new Object('abc)).toString()`

Comment: @jordanpaul `new Object("abc").toString() === "abc"` Stop making wild assumptions please.

Comment: Ok, then please be clear what it is you are asking. `new Object('abc') === "[object Object]"` is not true, as you implied in your first comment, because `new Object('abc')` does not return a string. If you try it in other browsers you will see that this is the case. I assume you are using safari; safari choses to log this as "[object Object]", but other browsers log it differently (in ff3, it shows as "abc { 0="a", 1="b", 2="c"}"). The reason `Array.prototype.sort.apply("abc")` does not work is because you can not alter a string with array accessors. In ff4, this triggers an error.

Comment: you might be right. It seems like webkit chooses to render the `new Object("string")` as `"[object Object]"` which might be to do with the interpreter

Answer (score 1):

`[[PrimitiveValue]]` of `String` is **not** `[object Object]` as demonstrated below:

```
console.log(String('foo'));
```

The issue in your code is the keyword `new`

```
console.log(new String('foo'));
```

The `new` keyword will return an instance of `Object` with the prototype of whatever type-constructor you passed.

Comment: I still don't see why only `new String` compared to any other native constructor mutates the value to "[object Object]"

Comment: `String` is an `Object`, so `String('foo')` returns a string 'foo' and `new String('foo')` returns an instance of that `Object`

Comment: Why does `new Boolean(true)` print the literal `true` and `new String("foo")` does not print the literal `"foo"`

Comment: I really have no idea but I'd say that because `Boolean` doesn't have any own methods other than `toString()` and `valueOf()` it's safe for the parser to return the boolean directly, you won't be altering/working it like you would with a String.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround for this.

```
function callArrayMethod(method, arg1, arg2) {
    if (arg2) {
        return Array.prototype[method].call(arg1.split(''), arg2).join('');
    }
    return Array.prototype[method].call(arg1.split(''), arg2).join('');
}
```

Usage:

```
> callArrayMethod('sort', 'cba');
"abc"
```

Comment: Ew! No. Never call array methods on anything _BUT_ an array. I'm asking why the conversion from `String` to `Object` returns `["object Object"]`

Comment: @Raynos Actually, I'm calling it on an array, since I'm splitting the string.

Comment: it's still a dirty hack to call string operations on `arg1` & `arg2` of type `string`.